# Unable to hold onto variable after fetching JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am using the highstocks charting library and JQuery for this question. I am attempting to create one chart that is partitioned into three pieces, each with a different set of data. To read in the data, I am using an example from the highstock site, with the following code:

```
var seriesOptions = [],
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

    $.each(names, function(i, name) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };            
        });
    });
```

After this code is processed, I use the `seriesOptions` variable as the series value for each of the three charts as such:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    // misc options
    series: [
        seriesOptions[0],
        seriesOptions[1],
        seriesOptions[2],
    ]
}
```

However, it seems that the seriesOptions variable is `null` after it comes out of the `$.getJSON()` method call. How can I get around this, and what is happening to the `seriesOptions` variable after the `$.getJSON()` call?

Thanks

EDIT: Specific error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`. I am pretty sure that this is referring to the `seriesOptions` variable, but I'll include it for clarity.

Comment: Im guessing you're executing the highcharts call before the AJAX call is done./

Comment: The highcharts call is after the `$.each()` statement in the file, does the browser skip over that block of code?

Comment: @aioko No but that code is asynchronous so the AJAX calls will be out of band of the normal JavaScript execution chain until the call returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably executing the `highCharts` call before the AJAX call has completed. You're also doing an AJAX call in a loop (albeit a small loop, it can still have the same general issues) - if you *can* - try and make this 1 AJAX call with all the params. If that's not an option - you can loop, and verify all the calls are done, then process:

```
var seriesOptions = [],
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

var completedCalls = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        seriesOptions.push({
            name: name,
            data: data
        });

        completedCalls++;    
        if (completedCalls == names.length) {
            //All ajax calls done, do highcharts magic!
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                // misc options
                series: [
                    seriesOptions[0],
                    seriesOptions[1],
                    seriesOptions[2],
                ]
            })
        }        
    });
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, spot on.

Comment: @War10ck -- Ahh damn, yep. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working after a little fiddling around. This is the solution that I used.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides an interface using `$.when` for resolving multiple ajax calls using deferred/promise objects. An example using your configuration can be seen below.

```
var seriesOptions = [];

$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=?'),
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?'),
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=goog-c.json&callback=?')
).done(function (r1, r2, r3) {
    seriesOptions.push({
        name: "MSFT",
        data: r1
    });
    seriesOptions.push({
        name: "AAPL",
        data: r2
    });
    seriesOptions.push({
        name: "GOOG",
        data: r3
    });

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        // misc options
        series: [
            seriesOptions[0],
            seriesOptions[1],
            seriesOptions[2],
        ]
    });
});
```